# Is this a good practices to keep a file list in php?

Tags: php, architecture

I find that using the php include file is extremely annoying. Especially using the relative path.... I was thinking it is a good idea to have a single.php file, store all the ".php" absolution path, and return it when the user need to include it...just like a little config file for storing all the file path, if there is any changing path, I just need to modify one place, What do you think? Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to define all your paths in one place so that you can do something like `include($headerFile);` or `include(getPath('header'));` everywhere instead of `include('../header.php.inc');`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with a config file for my projects and have some constants like:

```
define('INCLUDES_DIR'='/includes');
```

So now I can easily change that path. When including a file I use

```
include(INCLUDES_DIR . '/header.php');
```

Now I can easily change between versions. So if I'm testing some new things I can make a include_test folder, change the INCLUDES_DIR and the whole project runs on the new folder.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're using OOP, then you should really look into the [spl_autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) and [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) functions. If you aren't using OOP, then why no? ;-)

As to an includes file, I suppose that it is not the worst thing in the world (I guess you'd just have some form of lookup function which does the include for you?), but it could get bloated quickly and it could actually decrease portability.

Most frameworks (including a couple of home-grown ones I've encountered) will simply have some constant like BASEDIR and then just include files relative to BASEDIR. In those cases, moving things from folder to folder was really not too common because a good framework separates files along the MVC pattern.